# Redirect url in plugin to somewhere else?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, menus, pages, redirect

I am using **WP-SNAP Extended! v1.0.0** and I want to use this alphabetical menu as a sub-menu beneath my header. I managed to get the alphabetical menu in place, but now, if I click on a letter, it will show the posts on the page I am looking at and that is not good, because it overlaps the things that are already there. So you get a very chaotic website with many different content..

What I want to do is this: if I click on a letter, I want it to redirect it to a page where I output the posts that are with that letter. Now, it shows: **http://somesite.com/test/?snap=C** if I click on a letter. I want it to show **http://somesite.com/test/?page_id=68&snap=C**

How do I pull this off? I am using this function to get it: `<?php if (function_exists('wp_snap')) { echo wp_snap(); } ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it with hard coding. I know, it isn't a great answer, but there was no other choice. Redirecting this plugin wasn't possible.